# Kubernetes Persistent Volume: What happen if storage exceed capactity

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage

Below is my PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim and  config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/elasticsearch"


---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

The capacity and the requested resources is only 10Gb. But my elasticsearch instance, whose storage is mounted to `elasticsearch-pvc`, is currently taking about 30Gb on host. Is that expected behavior for `hostPath` PersistentVolume?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the difference between [resource](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/design/resources.html) `request` and `limit`.